# How are Ethereum 2.0 (post merge) block hashes computed?

Tags: blockchain, javascript, blocks, the-merge

I found in this link on [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67280/block-header-hash-calculation) that a block hash is calculated by using

```js
const blockData = [
        block.parentHash,
        block.sha3Uncles,
        block.miner,
        block.stateRoot,
        block.transactionsRoot,
        block.receiptsRoot,
        block.logsBloom,
        block.difficulty,
        block.number,
        block.gasLimit,
        block.gasUsed,
        block.timestamp,
        block.extraData,
        block.mixHash,
        block.nonce,
      ];
const txHash ="0x" + Buffer.from(keccak256(rlp.encode(blockData))).toString("hex");
```

This form to get the hash data is perfect for transactions before "the merge" so I want to know how data must be change to get the block hash post-merge